# Select Susbtr Field between two characters

Tags: php, mysql

I Have a problem to select a part of characters. Here's my field's content :

```
[{"index":1,"image":"un-nouveau-test-d-annonce_12_1.jpg","thumbnail":"un-nouveau-test-d-annonce_12_1_t.jpg"}]
```

I want to select `un-nouveau-test-d-annonce_12_1_t.jpg` only. But, the name is different in all fields.

```
field1 : un-nouveau-test-d-annonce_12_1_t.jpg
field2 : hello_ads_2.jpg
```

So, I want that my "select" select the first letter (u or h) to the end of the address (jpg in all cases).

I have this :

```
$img = "SELECT
    SUBSTR(images, LOCATE('l\":\"',images)+1, 
    (CHAR_LENGTH(images) - LOCATE('l\":\"',REVERSE(images)) - LOCATE('l\":\"',images))) 
    FROM  mq74m_adsmanager_ads";

$resultimg = mysql_query($img) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($resultimg) > 0)
{
    while ($rowimg = mysql_fetch_array($resultimg))
    {
        echo $rowimg['images'];
    }
}
```

But the result is empty.

Comment: This is the sign that you should normalize your database :)

Answer (score 0):

Extract all from database, then apply json_decode and you will obtain an array. After that you can do $result[$i]['image'] where $i is the index.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. How to use json_decode with MYSQL ?

Comment: $query = "SELECT images FROM table";
$results = mysql_query($query);
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
   $decoded = json_decode($row['images'], TRUE); // TRUE is put to return an array
   echo $decoded['image'];
}